# XML Based Meta Data Driven WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpftoolkit

I am working on a BI application in WPF. I am in the process of designing its architecture and am in search of a way to directly bind controls in the view to a xml which contains the metadata of the view. Do you think this is going to be possible? then how? or is it advisable to read off from the xml and generate the views accordingly?

**Edited**

Properties such as colors of charts, who created the chart, the next chart upon drilling down a chart, the user names and their passwords, user group names etc. are stored in XML files. When a user starts the application the dashboards he has created should be displayed; this happens with the retrieval of data from the back end and by assigning the correct chart colors. So if these data are available in the XML, my question is the best way to generate the charts and dashboards upon user request.

**Edited**
[image: Screenshot of a dashboard we currently load from xml, through a normal read write operation]

As I explained earlier as well, the problem is to store the metadata related to this application in the most efficient and structured way to call back upon a user loging in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What charting library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite understand what you are looking to do. If you just want to bind some UI control properties to data in an XML document, that's entirely possible. I blogged about it years ago [here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/04/binding-to-xml/).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best in your case would be to devide all possible data in the system by data classes - metatypes. after that, in xml, specify data metatype so your data would be always have metatype. And when, before view creation, you should read all metatypes for data you are intend to display and create screen controls according to that metatypes. After that you could load and display data. Such approach works well in my small programm and I thinks it would yield good results in your system too.

**[EDIT]**
OK, your application includes business domain (your business data, business logic and rules for data displaying). All this things you have spread among three parts: Model, View and ViewModel. As I understand correctly your question is stright about ViewModel.
For example your hypothetical application containы employee information and suppose every employee may have three types of information about he or she:

1. Personal information (Name, date of birth, photo, home address, mobile phone number)
2. Education information (information about education, list of completed training cources)
3. Proffesional experience information (list of succesfully completed commercial projects)

So we have domain - employee. This domain may be devided into three metatype:

1. Personal metatype
2. Education metatype
3. Proffesional experience metatype

For each metatype we should create subscreen which would display metatype information according to business rules. I'll recomend you to make metatype subscreens with MVC pattern because of in case of editing of data some special editing rule or data validation may be applyed. When we have each subscreen created we can be free to display each type of meta information in the system.
For example you application have loaded employee information. After that you can determine which metatype presented in loaded data and can force creation of appropriate subscreens. The last part of work is to pass appropriate data to each sub screen.

---

It was very vague explanation sorry for my english, if you have any question about I have explained feel free and ask question again

Comment: Hi Anton, thank you for your detailed answer. I was quite nearly doing the same thing you have explained. So far it worked alright. Could you please tell me more about "data classes - metatypes". I am new to WPF and C# as a whole; but catched up most of the stuff by now. There for pardon me if I am raising a stupid question here. More over please note that the entire application is being done on MVVM.

Comment: @picmate: my answer didnt fit in comment windows, so I had to edit y answer

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest use of XAML instead of XML.

XAML will not only let you define the UI but XAML also can contain your other metadata or config information that you can read/write in the form of XAML to directly your CLR class.

Benefits are,

1. Xaml serialization is exactly same as that of Xml's serialization
2. Xaml will give you powerful intellisense while editing in Visual Studio (xml also can give but you will have to create and update schema everytime you make changes to your configuration schema)
3. In case of intellisense, Xaml is better because it will automatically give validation errors
4. It will also allow you to use Enums
5. It will also hide/show members or classes based on inheritance hierarchy
6. You can load XAML from string coming from database as well
7. It will let you specify bindings as well if your object is derived from DependencyObject and you will be able to transfer or reuse the bindings in your UI

For example,

```
public class ScreenElement{
    public string Author {get;set;}
    public DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}
}

// XAML can not directly deal with generics so this step is
// necessary
public class ScreenElements : ObservableCollection<ScreenElement>
{
}

[ContentProperty("Elements")]
public class Screen
{
    public Screen(){
        this.Elements = new ScreenElements();
    }
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public bool ToolbarPresent {get;set;}

    // this attribute is necessary if 
    // you want to save Screen to xaml
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ScreenElements Elements {get; private set;}
}
```

And your Screen xaml can look like

```
<Screen xmlns="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        Title="Home Screen"
        ToolbarPresent="false"
        >
    <ScreenElement Author="Myself" DateCreated="..."/>
    <ScreenElement Author="Yourself" DateCreated="..."/>
</Screen>
```

You can create XAML resource and load it like...

```
Screen s = XamlReader.Load(.. resource uri to your XAML)
// and now you can use your "s" loaded with elements to 
// populate your UI

foreach(ScreenElement e in s.Elements){
    // use attributes of e to populate things..
}
```

Comment: Hi Akash, thanks for your lengthy and informative answer. Could you let me know where I will be able to store my data in this context. Maybe I am missing it when I read the answer. I will need to save the colors, the sql query which is used to retrieve the data, the vales passed from one query to the next in some format which is easiest to be regenerated upon the user loging in. I have attached a screenshot for you to understand the type of dashboards we create now, using xml.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see your screenshot, but you can consider your XAML as xml representation C# object model, you can create as many properties and collections to create hierarchy and you can pass on in the code from one level to another level.

Comment: Hi Akash, can you see the screenshot now? It took time for me to upload it. By the way how can I use your proposed solution in an MVVM context? Sorry, I am a bit confused.

Comment: Your View Model can contain ScreenElement and you have to make a custom control (your own) that will probably read ScreenElement and generate the graph based on properties defined in ScreenElement. Or you can even bind to properties directly like Model.CurrentScreenElement.AuthorName or Model.CurrentScreenElement.Query, you can as many properties in your ScreenElement class and bind them from your View. And your View+ViewModel will load its default or initial data from Xaml resource or text you have specified.

Comment: Hi Akash, I think I understand what you are talking about. Its better to try I guess. According to you we will basically be dumping all the meta data in to the xaml file, yeah? User names, passwords, colors etc.; in to the xaml through the object model.

Comment: Yes, infact XAML is another alternative of XML.

Comment: Thanks Akash, I will try and comment on it.